# How do I read and compare single bytes from .jpeg file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, jpeg

I need to read single bytes from a jpeg file. In other words, i have this hex dump from a jpg file: [The Yellow circled part is the one i need to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R64Z.png) and I need to write a simple C++ code that could read all the bytes until it gets to the interesting part. How can I, once I read one byte, compare it with a value I give to it?

I need this because after 5 bytes from that "FF" byte, it says my jpeg's dimensions in pixels and i need to retrieve them.

I'm sorry if I made some language mistakes but I'm not mother tongue.

Comment: Unless the image files are copies of each other, JPEG compression might lead to two seemingly equal images not being equal at all at the byte level. Not even uncompressed. Unless, of course, you want to get the JPEG file meta-data?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah understood, but I read that all jpegs files have, at some point in their hex dump, that same header which starts with FF C0 and which contains the image's dimensions in pixels. I don't know if I explained myself enough. Anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: The JPEG file format is an open format, there should be no problem finding references about its file-format, including the structure of all its meta-data like the file-header. There are also a few libraries that exist to read JPEG files, and which can extract the exact data you need, instead of you attempting to make your own loader.

Comment: If you want to read the file byte-wise, just open it like a binary file and read it byte by byte.  You could then put together a state machine to determine the region of interest and read it out that way.  Is that more along the lines of what you want?

Comment: It's not enough to search for `FF C0` since an earlier part of the file might contain it by pure coincidence. You really need to parse the file from the beginning, piece by piece. A pre-existing library is the easiest way to do that; I'd check out [IJG](http://www.ijg.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid voting on this post as this is not meant to be an actual answer to the question: this is only acting as a reference page. If you know of any other references in regards of the details of writing a JPG / JPEG loader feel free to edit this post and add the links below...

---

> #### Images
>
> [image: JPEG Format 1]

---

> #### Links
>
>   [Sardi : JPEG Format](http://vip.sugovica.hu/Sardi/kepnezo/JPEG%20File%20Layout%20and%20Format.htm)
>
>   [W3 : JPEG Format](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf)